# Is there any option for collections in Cocoalibspotify(Spotify IOS)?

Tags: ios, xcode, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

i can add tracks into playlist from the following code

```
[[SPSession sharedSession] playlistForURL:playList.spotifyURL callback:^(SPPlaylist *playlist) {
        [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:playlist timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notLoadedItems) {
            [playlist addItem:self.currentTrack atIndex:0 callback:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                [hud hide:YES];
            }];
        }];
    }];
```

here i want to know that is there any option for "collection" or "my collections" like Rdio ? i want add some tracks into my collections ..Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not at this time, no.